# Subtracting values to moment.js using input[type="range"]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, momentjs

I want to subtract dates to [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) using input[type="range"] but it's not working correctly. Here is my code:

JS

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="30">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script>
var now = moment().format('MMM DD, YYYY - hh:mm a');

$('input[type="range"]').on('change',function(){

    var timeValue = $(this).val();

    now = moment().subtract(timeValue,'minutes').format("MMM DD, YYYY - hh:mm a");
    console.log(timeValue);
    console.log(now);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force the value from the input into an integer, as it's a string.

```
var timeValue = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j9kVN/)

Comment: I see. This is definitely the answer that I am looking for. I'll be sure to parse all the values from text inputs to integers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you params are wrong way around:

```
var now = moment().subtract('minutes', timeValue).format("MMM DD, YYYY - hh:mm a");
```

'minutes' is the first param in subtract and then the timevalue.

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Fp5V9/2/)

But Kalley's answer also fixes the issue.

Comment: The add and subtract functions for moment.js has been accepting reverse syntax as of version 2.0.0 according to the documentation so the one that fixes the issue is Kalley's answer. I didn't know that range gives string as a value. Gotta take note of it from now on.